# How can I write a bash script that sets a variable that's available to the user in the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, scope

I want the user to be able to run a script which looks like this now:

```
# script.sh
export PASSPHRASE=123
```

and then be able to do this in the same terminal as that in which the script was evoked:

```
$ echo $PASSPHRASE
123
```

In other words, I want the variable in the script to be available to the user after the script has been run. How do I do that?

Comment: `source /path/to/script.sh` or shorter `. /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: Well, just do it. The environment variables are persistent during a session. All you have to take care of that you do not fork a new shell for the execution of a script, since after leaving that shell at the end of an execution all setting of _that_ shell will be lost again. You can do that by means of the `source` command. So `source ./myscript.sh` will do the trick.

Comment: Or `. /path/to/script.sh` (or, if it is in a directory listed on your PATH, then `. script.sh` — and it doesn't even need to be executable to be found and read).  The `.` command is the traditional Bourne shell syntax (and is the one supported by POSIX, so it will work with more shells).  The `source` command is an import from C shell supported by Bash — in Bash, the two are fully equivalent as far as I know, apart from the spelling.